# Is \, | \, equivalent to \mid?

Tags: spacing, macros, equations, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols

> Is `\mid` equivalent to `\, | \,` ?

I am asking this because, `\mid` does not cooperate with `\big`. However `\,\big| \,` works fine. I typically use these expressions when defining sets, for instance:
[image]

Comment: No. Use `\Bigm|`.

Comment: @egreg ah, thanks!

Comment: Or see the `\Set` example in the `mathtools` manual (I'm not personally a fan of using `\mid` for sets as it cannot be scaled, thus confusing syntax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not equivalent. The space around `\mid` is `\thickmuskip`, which is normally twice as big as `\thinmuskip` (which is what's inserted by `\,`).

If you want a bigger bar as a relation symbol, use

```
\Bigm|
```

(the `m` stands for “middle” and, by convention, this yields a relation symbol).

If you're on LaTeX, **don't** use `$$`. You should also use `\Bigl` for left delimiters and `\Bigr` for right delimiters.

Let's compare the results:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\Bigl\{ \sum_{k=1}^n k \,\Big|\, n\leq 5 \Bigr\} \\
\Bigl\{ \sum_{k=1}^n k \Bigm| n\leq 5 \Bigr\} \\
\Bigl\{\, \sum_{k=1}^n k \Bigm| n\leq 5 \Bigr\}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

In the last one I added a thin space to avoid a clash by moving the brace slightly farther than the summation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will accept it in 7 min. I am on latex and very often use $$... Could please either tell me why I should not use $$ or give me link with the answer to the question.

Comment: @Surb See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)